# Remove Events with Mapquest API

Tags: javascript, api, mapquest

I have a project when I am creating a single page application with backbone.js for a mobile platform.  I need to create several maps between "pages."  This works just fine, and the first map displayed works perfectly, however all of the other maps display fine, but none of the events work.  I.E. I can't scroll.  Works on chrome on the desk top.  Not on iPad.

Looking at the documentation for MQA.TileMap, there is a dispose function, but it is yet to be implemented I guess.  I tried to reset the maps with the MQA.EventManager, but to no avail.

Example:  page 1

```
<div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var options={
        elt:document.getElementById('map'),       
        zoom:15,                             
                latLng:{lng:longitude, lat: latitude},  
        mtype:'osm',                            
        bestFitMargin:0,                        
        zoomOnDoubleClick:true                  
    };

    /*Construct an instance of MQA.TileMap with the options object*/ 
    window.ReConMap = new MQA.TileMap(options);

    MQA.withModule('smallzoom', function() {
        var basic=new MQA.Poi( {lng:longitude, lat: latitude} );
        window.ReConMap.addShape(basic);
        window.ReConMap.addControl(
            new MQA.SmallZoom(),
            new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_LEFT, new MQA.Size(5,5))
        );
    });

</script>
```

Works just fine.  Then I click a button that clears out the body  and preform:

```
<div id="map2" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

if( window.ReConMap ){
        MQA.EventManager.clearAllListeners( window.ReConMap );
        window.ReConMap = null;
    }
 var options={
        elt:document.getElementById('map2'),       
        zoom:15,                             
                latLng:{lng:longitude, lat: latitude},  
        mtype:'osm',                            
        bestFitMargin:0,                        
        zoomOnDoubleClick:true                  
    };

    /*Construct an instance of MQA.TileMap with the options object*/ 
    window.ReConMap = new MQA.TileMap(options);

    MQA.withModule('smallzoom', function() {
        var basic=new MQA.Poi( {lng:longitude, lat: latitude} );
        window.ReConMap.addShape(basic);
        window.ReConMap.addControl(
            new MQA.SmallZoom(),
            new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_LEFT, new MQA.Size(5,5))
        );
    });

</script>
```

That displays just fine, but all of the scroll events don't work.  (I found it works on Chrome, but not on Android or iOS devices)

I know this is a long shot question, but any help would be great.

PLEASE NOTE:  The problem is not the map being displayed.  Only that the events are not working.  Not all of the code is here (exp: `longitude` and `latitude` are defined elsewhere)